# Web API MVC get query parameter from ng-table?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, ngtable

I've been trying to get ng-table(angular directive) work with a web api (ASP.NET MVC). I can load and page the data but the sorting or filtering won't work.

The weird thing is that the sorting or filtering will look like this in the URL:

http://localhost:46278/api/rating?count=10&filter%5Brating.name%5D=fs&page=1&sorting%5Brating.description%5D=asc

If you would "format" it, it would look like this:

**filter[rating.name] = fs 

sorting[rating.description] = asc**

I tried to get them with a string array or a dictionary (KeyValuePair)

But I can't get the values. So I can never filter or sort the data.

I hope you can give me some advice! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a helper class to deal with this. The URL isn't formatted in a way WebAPI expects, so couldn't get the ModelBinder to parse it automatically.

From your controller, call the helpers and provide the entire URL:

```
// Parse sortings
var sortings = TableHelpers.ParseSortings(Request.RequestUri).ToList();
// Parse filters
var filters = TableHelpers.ParseFilters(Request.RequestUri).ToList();
```

And the helper class

```
public static class TableHelpers
{
    public static IEnumerable<TableSorting> ParseSortings(Uri requestUri)
    {
        var regex = new Regex("sorting%5B(.+?)%5D=(asc|desc)");
        var matches = regex.Matches(requestUri.AbsoluteUri);
        return from Match match in matches
            select new TableSorting {Field = match.Groups[1].Value, Order = match.Groups[2].Value};
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TableFilter> ParseFilters(Uri requestUri)
    {
        var regex = new Regex("filter%5B(.+?)%5D=(.+?)(?:&|\\z)");
        var matches = regex.Matches(requestUri.AbsoluteUri);
        return from Match match in matches
            select new TableFilter {Field = match.Groups[1].Value, Value = match.Groups[2].Value};
    }
}

public class TableSorting
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Order { get; set; }
}

public class TableFilter
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this helper class specifically for ngTable?

Comment: Yes, the regex is written to parse the URLs ngTable generates

Comment: Okay, thanks I will try it when I have time. But it looks good on the first sight :) And if it works I'll accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

are you asking about directive syntax or your api?

in ng-table directive, insert in `<td>` tag `sorting` or/and `filtering` attrs, like:

```
<td width="10%" data-title="'NUM'|translate" filter="{ 'num': 'text' }" sortable="'num'"><span>{{item.num}}</span></td>
```

Comment: I already got that working :) I need to know how I can read the query string parameters in a Web API Controller when you use a server side array?